# When was the term "All lives matter" first used and what was it meant?

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains

These days these two terms "Black lives matter" and "All lives matter" are in the centre of the discussion.
Although, it is understood what "All lives matter" in context of "black lives matter", Can you please provide some details when "All lives matter" was originally used and what it was supposed to convey?

I have gone through couple of articles on this topic but none of them provided me satisfactory answer.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Lives_Matter

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.sportsnet.ca/basketball/nba/explaining-lives-matter-actually-means-say/sn-amp/

https://www.10tv.com/article/why-phrase-all-lives-matter-problematic-2020-jun

Comment: What research have you done? On the 'Net, perhaps?

Comment: @BillJ I have followed a Wikipedia page and other articles that showed up on Google search! They all are talking about the conflicts in between "BLM" and "ALM". https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Lives_Matter , https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.sportsnet.ca/basketball/nba/explaining-lives-matter-actually-means-say/sn-amp/

Comment: The first time I ever saw "all lives matter" was in response to "black lives matter". That's not to say the expression had never been used before, but I think the current BLM context is the first widespread use.

Comment: @BillJ please find my updated on the question

Comment: If you've identified sources that explain the term and its use, I don't understand why you still need it to be explained. Even a glance at the Wikipedia link in the question indicates it does a fair job. What are you actually asking if the information in the sources you provide is not sufficient?

Comment: @JasonBassford    I wanted to know about the origin of this term. When it was originally used and what was it's meaning? All my research and the provided links are talking about current situation of 'BLM' vs 'ALM'.